# Removal of component in an XML listing from custom theme

Tags: magento2.2, custom-theme

I wish to remove a part from an XML page without editing the core file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<listingToolbar name="listing_bottom" template="Aheadworks_AdvancedReviews/ui/grid/toolbar">
    <paging name="listing_paging" class="Aheadworks\AdvancedReviews\Ui\Component\Review\Frontend\Listing\Paging" component="Aheadworks_AdvancedReviews/js/product/view/review/grid/paging/paging"/>
    <component name="awArWriteReviewControlListingBottom" component="Aheadworks_AdvancedReviews/js/product/view/review/write-review-control" displayArea="right-column"/>
</listingToolbar>       
</listing>
```

The part i wish to remove is awArWriteReviewControlListingBottom.  How would I do this please in Magento 2.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it seems you can use the displayArea rather than trying to remove the component.

Setting;

```
displayArea="nothing"
```

seems to have removed it